# Proof that the function $f(x,y)=3x^4-4x^2y+y^2$ has no relative minimun in any disk

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I'm trying to prove that the function $f: \mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=3x^4-4x^2y+y^2$ has no local minimum in any disk, but my proof is long and very inefficient. Any ideas?

I started my proof noticing that $f(x,y)=(3x^2-y)(x^2-y)$

Then $f(x,y) < 0$ if $3x^2>y>x^2$ and $f(x,y) \geq 0$ otherwise.

In the case where $3x^2>y>x^2$:

Let $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} ^2 | 3x^2>y>x^2\}$.
Let $\delta>0$ and $D=B_\delta (0,0)-\{(0,0)\}$ an arbitrary disk.

If $u \in S \cup D$, then I tried to proof that always exists $v \in S \cup D$ such that $f(u) > f(v)$ and in this way, there's no local minimum in the disk. But my proof is very very long.

And I didn't do the proof of the second case (i.e., $u \notin  S$).

So, am I in the correct way, or there's an easier way for doing this?

Comment: Could you please include an outline of your proof? It's hard for anyone to improve it if no one knows what it is. Also, is $f$ a function of two or three variables? Your title and the body of your question seem to disagree on that.

Comment: @RobertHoward Edited

Comment: Edited? They still don't agree.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; I didn't realized what was wrong

Comment: ***Hint*** what about calculus?

Comment: I guess calculus alone isn't enough!  See my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

$f(x,y)=3x^4-4x^2y+y^2,\tag 1$

we may investigate the existence and locaion of critical points by first taking

$f_x = 12x^3 - 8xy, \tag 2$

$f_y = -4x^2 + 2y, \tag 3$

we see that

$f_y = 0 \Longrightarrow y = 2x^2, \tag 4$

and then

$f_x = 0 \Longrightarrow 12x^3 = 8xy = 8x(2x^2) = 16x^4 \Longrightarrow 4x^3 = 0 \Longrightarrow x = 0; \tag 5$

it follows from these two statements that *the only critical point of $f$* occurs at

$(x, y) = (0, 0); \tag 6$

since relative minima are critical, we need merely investigate the nature of this the sole critical point of $f$; a first step is to compute the second derivatives; we have

$f_{xx} = 36x^2 - 8y, \tag 7$

$f_{yy} = 2, \tag 8$

$f_{xy} = f_{yx} = -8x; \tag 8$

we may now form the Hessian of $f$:

$H[f](x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 36x^2 - 8y & -8x \\ -8x & 2 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 9$

at our critical point $(0, 0)$ this becomes

$H[f](0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{10}$

since $H[f](0, 0)$ is singular, we see that the critical point $(0, 0)$ is *degenerate*, and we can't *directly* assert, based upon $H[f](0, 0)$, whether the point is a local minimum or not, or indeed just what the topological characteristics of the *level sets* of $f$ in a neighborhood of $(0, 0)$ might be.  Therefore a change in direction is mandated.

We observe that

$f(x, y) > 0 \tag{11}$

on both the $x$- and $y$-axes; that is

$f(x, 0), \; f(0, y) > 0, \; \forall 0 \ne x, y \in \Bbb R; \tag{12}$

this fact, together with

$f(0, 0) = 0 \tag{13}$

*suggests* that we attempt to find the curves $y(x)$ along which

$f(x, y(x)) = 0, \tag{14}$

since if $f(x, y)$ undergoes a change sign from positive to negative, which must occur arbitrarily close to $(0, 0)$ if this point is *not* a local minimum of $f$, it *must* occur as one of these curves $y(x)$ is crossed.  We thus write the condition
(14) as a quadratic equation in $y$ with coefficients functions of $x$:

$y^2 - 4x^2 y + 3x^4 = 0;, \tag{15}$

which we may solve *via* the quadratic formula:

$y = \dfrac{4x^2 \pm \sqrt{16x^4 - 12x^4}}{2} = \dfrac{4x^2 \pm \sqrt{4x^4}}{2} = \dfrac{4x^2 \pm 2x^2}{2} = 3x^2, x^2; \tag{16}$

it follows that $f(x, y) = 0$ along the curves

$y = x^2, 3x^2, \tag{17}$

this suggests we investigate the sign of $f(x, y)$ along

$y = 2x^2, \tag{18}$

which lies between the two curves (17) in the $xy$-plane; and we have

$f(x, 2x^2) = (2x^2)^2 - 4x^2(2x^2) + 3x^4 = 4x^4 - 8x^4 + 3x^4 = -x^4 < 0 \; \text{for} \ x \ne 0; \tag{19}$

this shows $f(x, y) < 0$ arbitrarily close to $(0, 0)$, so the origin *cannot* be a local minimum of $f(x, y)$; since $(0, 0)$ is the only critical point of $f(x, y)$, this function has no local minimum in the plane, hence not in any disk. $OE\Delta$.

The region where $f(x, y) < 0$ is apparently squeezed between the two curves $y = x^2$ and $y = 3x^2$, and narrows to a sort of cusp as $x \to 0$; so it is very tiny, a mere sliver near the origin; hence, hard to find.

But note the methods here are primarily *heuristic* in nature; the solution involved some (hopefully) well-guided guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/Guide:**  Find the critical points (points $(a,b)$ where the gradient  $\nabla f(a,b)=0$).

For those points, look at the second partials.  Let $D=f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b)-(f_{xy}(a,b))^2$. If $D\gt0$, and $f_{xx}\gt0$, it's a local minimum.

If $D=0$, other methods must be used.

Comment: At $(0, 0)$, $f_{xx} = f_{xy} = 0$; $f_{yy} = 2$ so I guess we're going with the "other methods"?  But what?

Comment: It seems like $(0,0)$ is the only critical point; is this enough to claim that $f$ has not another relative minimum at any disk?

Comment: @rowcol yes, I think so

Comment: @RobertLewis not sure.  I got diverted into Morse theory, but couldn't find anything about degenerate critical points.

Comment: Here is an article on degenerate critical points,  using Taylor series:  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689393?read-now=1&seq=5#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @ChrisCuster:  I solved it, but I had to use some non-differential methods.  See my answer.